# Completing read a directory or an element from a list

Tags: completion, ido, completing-read

I'm making some functions to interact with Mercurial.  Many Mercurial commands take a repository as an argument, and that argument can be specified either by a path to the root of the repository or by a repo name.  These repo names can be configured in the user's `.hgrc` file, and it is easy to get a list of the names that are defined.

I'd like to make a completing read function that dynamically completes a path to a directory ***or*** an item from a list.  I'd like it to work just like `ido-read-directory-name`, but with the items from a list also offered as options.

I've been digging through the documentation, and also through `mini_buffer.el` and `ido.el`.  The only hint I have so far is that I can override the variable `read-file-name-function`, but it seems like I'd end up reimplementing a lot of functionality for dynamically completing directory names.

Does anyone have any guidance for me?  Or perhaps an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
(let* ((dir-table (apply-partially #'completion-table-with-predicate
                                 #'completion-file-name-table
                                 #'file-directory-p
                                 'strict))
       (my-table
        (completion-table-in-turn <reponamesfromhg> dir-table)))
  (completing-read "Foo:" my-table))
```

Comment: Very cool, thanks!  How can I make this only complete directories?  And how can I get this to work with ido?

Comment: See updated code to constrain the completion to directories.  As for IDO, I do not know why it wouldn't work with it, but it might be difficult to fix it (IOW you might be better off trying to get the standard completion to look more like IDO, e.g. by enabling `icomplete-mode`).

Comment: Should it be `apply-partially`?

Comment: Thanks for getting me this far, Stefan!  I use `ido-vertical-mode`, so unfortunately `icomplete-mode` isn't quite what I want.  I would still love for this to work basically the same as `ido-read-directory-name`, if anyone else has any ideas.

Comment: There's no good reason why you couldn't have an `icomplete-vertical-mode`.